# How translate select options with vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, frontend

I want to translate the options found inside the contract_project_type array,

this is my select code:

```
<b-form-select
              :options="contract_project_types"
              v-model="form.contract_data.contract_project_type"
              id="contract_project_types"
              :state="validate(form.contract_data.contract_project_type)"

          ></b-form-select>
```

and my Data is :

```
data: {
contract_project_types: [
      'digital_work_city',
      'general_company'
      ]
}
```

i don't know how to translate these two options.
I tried to put `this.$t('digital_work_city')` `this.$t('general_company')` but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. May be, it hasn't reacted to change a language.

```
computed: {
    contract_project_types() {
         return [
           this.$t('digital_work_city'),
           this.$t('general_company')
      ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to get `$t` from the `this` context when outside of a template.

```js
data() {
    return { contract_project_types: [
      this.$t('digital_work_city'),
      this.$t('general_company')
      ]
    }
}
```

You may also try

```js
this.$i18n.t('digital_work_city')
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't works

Comment: what library are you using for translation?   i added another option to the solution

Comment: I18n ruby on rails